Widen/narrow line sections of plot so that x-axis breaks at peaks are evenly spaced
I am making a simple line plot with ggplot2 with "signal" peaks over time in the x-axis.
For a little bit of background, this specific plot is what is called a "chromatogram", and shows signal intensity, in relative fluorescence units, plotted over time. DNA bases (one of A, C, G, T) are "called" (assigned) at each peak intensity.
I am using the sangerseqR ab1 file example for my MWE below. I just load the data, create a data frame with the trace data to plot (the intensity values), and define the DNA sequence as each of the bases called at the peaks, at specific time points in the x-axis.
I just plot a small portion of the DNA sequence (trimmed from front and back) for simplicity.
This is all fine, and works as expected:
#read in data from sangerseqR example
seq_obj <- sangerseqR::readsangerseq(system.file("extdata", "heterozygous.ab1", package = "sangerseqR"))

#create data frame with trace data to plot
trace_df <- as.data.frame(seq_obj@traceMatrix) #columns for A, C, G, T
names(trace_df) <- c('A','C','G','T')
trace_df$time <- seq_len(nrow(trace_df))
trace_df <- as.data.frame(tidyr::pivot_longer(trace_df, -time, names_to = "base", values_to = "signal"))

#create data frame with base (letter) calls at the specific times (corresponding with trace peaks)
basecall <- unlist(strsplit(toString(seq_obj@primarySeq), ""))
basepos <- seq_obj@peakPosMatrix[,1] #first column for primary seq
base_df <- data.frame(call=basecall, time=basepos, callnum5=seq_along(basepos), callnum3=rev(seq_along(basepos)))

#join both data frames
trace_df <- dplyr::left_join(trace_df, base_df, by="time")
trace_df$call <- ifelse(trace_df$call==trace_df$base, trace_df$call, NA)

#trim data from 5' (top) and 3' (bottom) to plot only a small section of the sequence
trim5 <- 50
trim3 <- 500
startpos <- min(which(trace_df$callnum5==trim5))
endpos <- max(which(trace_df$callnum3==trim3))
trace_sub <- trace_df[startpos:endpos,]

#define colors, x-axis breaks and labels
basecolors <- c("green","blue","black","red")
xbreaks <- trace_sub$time[which(trace_sub$call==trace_sub$base)]
xlabels <- trace_sub$call[which(trace_sub$call==trace_sub$base)]

#make plot in ggplot2
P <- ggplot2::ggplot(trace_sub, ggplot2::aes(x=time, y=signal, group=base, colour=base)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=basecolors) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks, labels=xlabels) +
  ggplot2::theme_light()
grDevices::pdf(file="test.pdf", height=2, width=20)
print(P)
grDevices::dev.off()

This produces the following plot, which looks perfect (identical to the sangerseqR::chromatogram() function output), but is not exactly as I want it.

Note the following. In a perfect chromatogram, we should see evenly-spaced peaks (and bases called at the peaks), but this is rarely the case, and certainly not the case in this example.
For my purposes (I want to compare a few almost-identical sequences by aligning/stacking their chromatograms), I need the x-axis breaks at the peaks (corresponding with the bases called) to be evenly spaced.
I want to ignore the time variable and have the bases appear at an equal distance from one another. In technical terms, the "basecall windows" need to have the same width.
For this, the peaks in the plot need to be widened or narrowed accordingly. This is something that different commercial software do, but I cannot think of what formula to apply to the data, so I can visualize the plot in such way.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks.

Any chance you can provide an example of your expected figure?

I wouldnt know how to make it... it would be the letters on the x-axis more close together and evenly spaced, and the peaks "compressed" accordingly

Create a data frame containing the times and new x-axis breaks using seq.
Xbreaks <- data.frame(time=xbreaks,
                      xbreaks=seq(from=min(xbreaks), 
                                  to=max(xbreaks), 
                                  length.out=length(xbreaks)))

Then join this to the original data frame on "time" and replace the NAs by linear interpolation.
trace_sub |>
  dplyr::full_join(Xbreaks, by="time") |>
  dplyr::mutate(time=zoo::na.approx(xbreaks), .by=base) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=signal, group=base, colour=base)) +
  geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=basecolors) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=Xbreaks$xbreaks, labels=xlabels) +
  theme_light()




Edit:
If the whole dataset (trace_df) is used instead, which includes NA at the start and end, then approxExtrap from the Hmisc package can be used to extrapolate these NA after the linear interpolation.
xbreaks <- trace_df$time[which(trace_df$call==trace_df$base)]
xlabels <- trace_df$call[which(trace_df$call==trace_df$base)]

Xbreaks <- data.frame(time=xbreaks,
                      xbreaks=seq(from=min(xbreaks), 
                                  to=max(xbreaks), 
                                  length.out=length(xbreaks)))

Linear interpolation
trace_df2 <- trace_df |>
  dplyr::full_join(Xbreaks, by="time") |>
  dplyr::mutate(time=zoo::na.approx(xbreaks, na.rm=FALSE), 
                id=row_number(), .by=base) 

Linear extrapolation
trace_df2$time[is.na(trace_df2$time)] <- Hmisc::approxExtrap(
     x=trace_df2$id[!is.na(trace_df2$time)], 
     y=trace_df2$time[!is.na(trace_df2$time)], 
     xout=trace_df2$id[is.na(trace_df2$time)])$y

This gives

          time base signal call callnum5 callnum3 xbreaks id
1  -0.04721754    A      0 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  1
2  -0.04721754    C     25 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  1
3  -0.04721754    G    281 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  1
4  -0.04721754    T      0 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  1
5   1.30185497    A      0 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  2
6   1.30185497    C     29 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  2
7   1.30185497    G    284 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  2
8   1.30185497    T      0 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  2
9   2.65092749    A      0 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  3
10  2.65092749    C     35 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  3
11  2.65092749    G    290 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  3
12  2.65092749    T      0 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  3
13  4.00000000    A      1 <NA>        1      605       4  4
14  4.00000000    C     47 <NA>        1      605       4  4
15  4.00000000    G    301    G        1      605       4  4
16  4.00000000    T      0 <NA>        1      605       4  4
17  5.34907251    A      2 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  5
18  5.34907251    C     67 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  5
19  5.34907251    G    321 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  5
20  5.34907251    T      0 <NA>       NA       NA      NA  5

Which can then be plotted as before:
trace_df2 |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=time, y=signal, group=base, colour=base)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=basecolors) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=Xbreaks$xbreaks, labels=xlabels) +
  ggplot2::theme_light()




Hi @Edward if you have time, I found a caveat that I am not sure how to debug... I get the following error when I skip the trim step, using trace_df instead of trace_sub:
Error in dplyr::mutate():
ℹ In argument: time = zoo::na.approx(xbreaks).
ℹ In group 1: base = "A".
Caused by error:
! time must be size 16215 or 1, not 7201.

It looks like it happens whenever there are NAs top and/or bottom of the data frame. It did not happen before because the trimmed data frame started and ended at the top of a peak (right on a base)... but not sure how to make this answer extended to the non-trim case

Why can't you use trace_sub? Your breaks and labels will also change then, right?

ok to avoid confusion, try the following instead: define trace_sub with startpos=1 (no left trim), the same error occurs

ok - I'll take a look when I am free ...

no rush! and many thanks for everything, I comment here if I manage to debug it

You can try adding na.rm=FALSE to the na.approx() call. This will leave the NA at the start and end as is, and result in those rows not being plotted.

thanks! I think it's ok like this... there is no way to preserve and interpolate that leading and trailing data lost then, right?

Well, I suppose you could continue the times backward and forward until the end of the data. But na.approx doesn't do that. You'll need another way to impute the NA based on the existing values in time so that all are equidistant. I think approxExtrap from Hmisc package will help in this case.
